# How to interpret a question regarding a bijection from arbitrary functions $\mathcal{F}$, to a powerset $\mathcal{P}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory

This is for homework, and as such I'm hoping to gain clarification on the question rather than be given a proof for it.

Question:

Let S be a set and let $\mathcal{P}$ be the power set of S. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of functions $\mathcal{f}$ : S $\rightarrow \{0,1\}$.

Prove that there is a natural bijection from $\mathcal{F}$ onto $\mathcal{P}$ defined by

$$ \mathcal{f} \mapsto \{ s \in S : \mathcal{f} (s) = 1 \} $$

Confusion:

I am not sure which quantifiers are to be considered here. This is mapping the subset of the functions $ \mathcal{F} $ which return $ 1 $ when a set $ s \in S $ is 'put into them' onto those same sets in $ \mathcal{P} $.

Are we saying that each of these functions in $\mathcal{F}$ map to exactly one $ s \in \mathcal{P} $? I.e., no function returns $1$ for more than one set $s$, and every $s$ returns $1$ and every $ s \in S $ is mapped to by exactly one function?

How can there be no function in this arbitrary set of functions which returns $1$ for more than one $ s \in S $?

Comment: For any $A\subseteq S$, $f_A$ is the function such that $f_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$, and $f_A(x)=0$ if $x\not\in A$. We are mapping the function $f_A$ to $A$.

Comment: Thank you. I have no idea how I misread that so thoroughly

Comment: You are welcome. If we know $f_A$, we know $A$, and vice-versa. Formally, this is expressed by saying that the map $\varphi$ that takes $f_A$ to $A$ ($\varphi(f_A)=A$) is a bijection from the set of functions from $S$ to $\{0,1\}$ to the set of all subsets of $S$, that is, the powerset of $S$.